# SAS/R calculate distance between two groups

Tags: r, sas, distance

I would like to calculate distance between two groups.
I am very confused.

I have a two data sets. One is about a company and one is about employees.

I would like to find out how their age( a company in which an employee is hired and an employee)  are similar or not. 
I think I need to standarize also..

1. calcuate euclidean distance between each person and a company. (4-5 people in a company)
2. calculate euclidean distance between each person and a company in industry level.

My dataset is like this:

```
person person_age    company company_age industry              

1        50             1       5         1

2        40             1       5         1

3        30             2        1        1

4        20             2        1        1

5        25             3        8        2
```

The following code will reproduce my data.frame:

```
person <- 1:5
person_age <- c(50,40,30,20,25)
company <- c(1,1,2,2,3)
company_age <- c(5,5,1,1,8)
industry <- c(1,1,1,1,2)
myData <- data.frame(person, person_age, company, company_age, industry)
```

Please help me.
I don't mind using SAS or R.
I am very confused.

Comment: you are correct about being confused. What's your definition of "distance"?

Comment: I would like to calculate such as euclidean distance.  thank you for asking a question.

Comment: Do you mean to find out if the age of the employees in one company is similar to another company?

Comment: euclidean distance on which variables? You will never be able to encode in a programming language that which you cannot explain clearly in plain language.

Comment: I mean that age of employees in one company is similar to age of the company.

Comment: Why not use ancova then?

Comment: JD.. I am sorry.I tried to explain some more.. I would like to calculate the distance between company_age and person_age

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you just want Euclidean distance on each person's age you can do something like:

```
d <- dist(myData[c("person","person_age")])
```

Your question is still incredibly malformed. For example, what does "calcuate [sic] euclidean distance between each person and a company" mean?

If you just want to know the distance between each person and the company they work for, you could code that as:

```
 with(myData, ((person_age - company_age)^2)^.5 )
```

which is simply the 2d Euclidean distance formula

Comment: who knows. Depends on what the OP is looking for :)

Answer (score -4):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559384/how-to-find-the-euclidean-distance-of-two-vectors-in-r) discusses about calculating Euclidean distance. Convert the data into two vectors and follow the steps.

Comment: PS "Measure theory and Lebesgue integration" -- really?  That's a bit like saying "to replace your exhaust system, you should go study metallurgy" ...