# calculating the distance from center to each data points

Tags: r

Hi I want to calculate the distance from center to each data points
I have used the following codes but it's not working, df is my dataframe and c1 is center
Thanks in advance

```
        dist <- NULL
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)) dist[i] <- euc.dist(df[i,],c1[i,])
        dist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Euclidean distance of two vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559384/euclidean-distance-of-two-vectors)

Answer (score 2):

And my solution as well:

Let data be matrix m:

```
     x y
[1,] 2 3
[2,] 5 6
[3,] 3 2
[4,] 5 1
[5,] 4 1
[6,] 6 8
```

Then centers are given by:

```
cnt = c(mean(m[,1]),mean(m[,2]))
```

So the code returning vector of distance between every row of m and cnt will be:

```
apply(m,1,function(x,cnt) {(sqrt((x[1] - cnt[1])^2+(x[2]-cnt[2])^2))},cnt)
```

And the result is:

```
[1] 2.223611 2.635231 1.900292 2.635231 2.505549 4.859127
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to deal with the problem: calculating all distances between points in df, or just with a center.

First approach (not efficient, you calculate all distances and get only a little subset):

```
set.seed(123)
mydf <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
c1 = c(x=3, y=4)
mydf <- rbind(c1,mydf)
as.matrix(dist(mydf))[-1,1] #exclude distance from the center to itself
```

And the second:

```
c1 = c(x=3, y=4)
euc.dist <- function(x1) sqrt(sum((x1 - c1) ^ 2))
set.seed(123)
mydf <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
apply(mydf, 1, euc.dist)
```

Results are the same:

```
4.076530 4.179765 4.213305 4.028456 4.407819 4.282502 4.494677 4.484104 4.413574 3.967853
```