# Determine what is the closest x,y point to the center of a cluster

Tags: r

I have the following data with random clusters:

```
iris$cluster = sample(0:1, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE)
```

Now I calculate the centers of the two clusters using the following code:

```
centers=iris %>% 
 group_by(cluster) %>% 
 summarise_at(vars(matches("Sepal")), mean)
```

Now I would like to calculates for each row in the dataset whether they are closer to the center of cluster 1 of the center
of cluster 2. So basically the euclidean distance of center 0 vs 1 for row 1,2,3 etc....

Any thoughts on what is the most efficient what to do this is R?

Comment: The problem of finding the distance of points to the center has been solved here (remember Pythagaros): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559384/euclidean-distance-of-two-vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559384/euclidean-distance-of-two-vectors) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099730/calculating-the-distance-from-center-to-each-data-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099730/calculating-the-distance-from-center-to-each-data-points)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculating the distance from center to each data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099730/calculating-the-distance-from-center-to-each-data-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the dimensionality of your problem, one method is to create a permutation of centers with each row and then find the minimum for each row

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

#create data
DT <- setDT(copy(iris))
set.seed(0L)
cols <- grep("^Sepal", names(DT), value=TRUE)
centers <- DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), 
    by=.("cluster"=sample(0:1, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE)), 
    .SDcols=cols]
setnames(centers, cols, paste0("mean_", cols))

CJ.dft <- function(...) {
    Reduce(f=function(x, y) cbind(x[rep(1:nrow(x), times=nrow(y)),], y[rep(1:nrow(y), each=nrow(x)),]),
        x=list(...)[-1],
        init=..1)
} #CJ.dft

crossJoinMtd <- function() {
    #cross join data with centers
    ans <- CJ.dft(DT[, rn:=.I], centers)

    #find the closest cluster
    ans[,
        .(ClosestCluster=cluster[which.min((Sepal.Length - mean_Sepal.Length)^2 + (Sepal.Width - mean_Sepal.Width)^2)]), 
        by=.(rn)]
}
```

Sample usage:

```
crossJoinMtd()
#      rn ClosestCluster
#  1:   1              1
#  2:   2              0
#  3:   3              0
#  4:   4              0
#  5:   5              1
# ---                   
#146: 146              1
#147: 147              0
#148: 148              1
#149: 149              1
#150: 150              0
```

some timings:

```
microbenchmark(crossJoinMtd(),
    times=100L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
# crossJoinMtd() 2.7325 3.03085 3.558447 3.26885 3.58805 14.6075   100
```

If OP can provide more details on the number of clusters or dimensionalities, it probably can be further optimized.